# Rollup Summary Fields with multi currency are not working on Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, roll-up-summary, multi-currency

I have a Master-Detail relationship between two custom objects. A rollup summary field sums up a currency field on all detail objects with an specific record type. The Rollup summary field is displayed on the standard layout of the master object. Multi-currency is enabled on my org.

As you can see the conversion is working just fine on the desktop but in Salesforce1 it displays no value for the field if any detail object has another currency than the master object.

Desktop view

[image: Desktop view]

Mobile view

[image: Mobile view]

There is no code involved.

Has anyone ever experienced the same error?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if the fact that you once had advanced currency management enabled may be affecting this if you ever used it. Sometimes when you turn a feature on and use it, I believe certain internal 'flags' might get set. So even though you turn it off, there could be something internally that indicates that it was used. Again, this is all speculation on my part but it is based on a recent experience with trying to delete an approval workflow to replace it with a new one.

Even though I disabled the workflow, one user had used it to get something approved and this prevented it from being deleted. I had to delete the record that was approved, empty the recycle bin, re-create the original record, and resubmit it for approval. Just a thought.

One thing is for sure though - advanced currency management does get in the way of doing roll-ups like this. There is an Idea that you could vote up if it bothers you. It bothers me ... a lot!

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqMq

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the dated exchange rates feature (enable advanced currency management) enabled? If you don't need it, try disabling that and re-test. Roll-up summary doesn't seem to work well if you have both multi-currency and advanced currency managed enabled at the same time.

Comment: Even while having disabled advanced currency management it still doesn't populate the Roll-ups.